# remove some file on usb flasdisk

Tags: files, uninstall, directory

I want to remove just some files on flash disk in ubuntu, usually, I just right-click by mouse in windows and erase them. but I can't find it in ubuntu. I have already erased any file that contains in pc hard disk by the terminal and done. but I can open USB flash disk by terminal to erase just some files not to formated it all. but it cant.[this my folder image files on my flasdisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJGsW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the file and click "Move to Trash".
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIT8Q.png)

Comment: To permanently delete the file, press and hold the shift key while you do the above.